# C# Powershell Runspace as User, not machine account

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a site that I am trying to run a vbscript from a powershell runspace (sounds weird but it was the easiest way I thought). My problem is the powershell script is running as the local machine account and not the user who is running it. Any help on fixing this would be appreciated. I tried using the impersonationcontext found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158 but was unsuccessful. Thanks in advance.

```
protected void btnRemMaint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtOutput.Text = "";
        txtOutput.Text = "Remove Maintenance Results";
        txtOutput.Text += Environment.NewLine;

        string servers;
        servers = txtServers.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");

        while (servers[servers.Length - 1].ToString() == ",")
            servers = servers.Substring(0, servers.Length - 1);

        System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
        impersonationContext =
            ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

        //Insert your code that runs under the security context of the authenticating user here.

        string script = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\VRS\\Admins\\PSScripts\\AMMaintMode.vbs";
        string mode = "/maint:0";
        string serv = "/server:" + servers;
        string ccserv = "/ccserver:calntmgt501";
        using (
        RunspacePool runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool())
        {
            // open it
            runspace.Open();

            // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
            PowerShell pipeline = PowerShell.Create();

            pipeline.RunspacePool = runspace;
            pipeline.AddCommand("cscript");
            pipeline.AddArgument(script);
            pipeline.AddArgument(mode);
            pipeline.AddArgument(serv);
            pipeline.AddArgument(ccserv);

            // execute the script
            IAsyncResult pipeResults = pipeline.BeginInvoke();
            PSDataCollection<PSObject> pipeOutput = pipeline.EndInvoke(pipeResults);

            //pipeline.Invoke();
            for (int i = 0; i < pipeOutput.Count; i++)
            {
                txtOutput.Text += pipeOutput[i].BaseObject.ToString();
                txtOutput.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }

            runspace.Close();
        }

        impersonationContext.Undo();

        txtServers.Text = "";
    }
```

the output results are as follows:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> AppManager Maintenance Mode CLI V2.1
>
> Connecting to Control Center...   Server calntmgt501\NQCCDB via Windows
>   Authentication
>   *** Failed to connect to server. Verify credentials. Error:
>   *** Login failed for user 'BLACKROCK\USPMVVMT001$'.

Comment: What's the APP Pool running as?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. BLACKROCK\USPMVVMT001$ which is the built in system account.

Comment: the app pool identity is the account executing the code. So why do you say it's not running as the user run it?

Comment: I need it to run as the user who is visiting the website, not the app pool. sorry for not being clear on that.

Comment: are you receiving credentials from the user of the site via integrated windows authentication?

Comment: I'm not asking for it but should be able to get them from the (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity   I was able to modify my vbs script to take a sql username and password to make it work, but would be nice to figure this piece out.

Comment: In order to impersonate you have to receive the credentials from the client using some method such as integrated windows authentication. You can't just impersonate any user.

Answer (score 0):

If the web site is using Windows Authentication, specifically Kerberos, you will have to enable delegation.  This is known as the "Double Hop" problem.  More specificially, you will need to domain administrator to enable constrained delegation.  The 'constrained' part mean you want to limit the delegation to just those services the web server needs to connect to.

Otherwise, all you would need to do is get a Domain Admin to hit your web site and you could use their credentials to do anything you wish. That would be a huge security issue.